# Array remains empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to load some text from a file, split it by `\n` and push every line into an array:

```
var entries = new Array();
$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadFile(); 
    console.log(entries.length) // Result: 0
});

function loadFile(){
    $.get('file.txt', function(data) {
        console.log(data); // my file is shown
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        $.each(lines, function(key, value) {
            entries.push(value);
        });

    }, 'text'); 
}
```

I can see the contents of my file in the console, so the file is being loaded, but my array remains empty, its length is `0`.

Why the lines won't be pushed into my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous function so you should show the length in callback after getting the response `data` :

```
var entries = new Array();
$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadFile();
});

function loadFile(){
    $.get('file.txt', function(data) {
        console.log(data); // my file is shown

        var lines = data.split("\n");
        $.each(lines, function(key, value) {
            entries.push(value);
        });

        console.log(entries.length) // that will return the true length

    }, 'text'); 
}
```

Check [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could call your function in the place of `console.log(entries.length)`.